# Bucle infinito al ingresar un número no entero

Tags: java, netbeans

He hecho este programa, pero cuando introduzco un valor no entero, cae en un bucle infinito. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que salga del bucle, pidiendo el número de nuevo?

```java
public class Prubea1 {

    public static final int MINIM_NUM = 1;
    public static final int MAXIM_NUM = 15;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numero = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //modifico boolean dadaCorrecta a false para que entre el dato
        boolean dadaCorrecta = false;
        boolean numeroCorrecte = false;

        while (!numeroCorrecte) {

            System.out.print("Entra un valor entre 1 - 15: ");
            dadaCorrecta = scan.hasNextInt();

            if (dadaCorrecta) {

                numero = scan.nextInt();
                // pongo dadaCorrecta  a false puesto que aun no ha entrado.
                dadaCorrecta = false;
                if ((numero < 1) || (numero > 15)) {

                    System.out.print("vuelva a introducirlo");
                    dadaCorrecta = true;

                } else {
                    numeroCorrecte = true;
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("dada incorrecta, te que ser un sencer, torni a introduir un numero");

            }
        }
        if ((numero >= 1) && (numero <= 15)) {
            System.out.println("ho has encertat");
            System.out.println("Correcto");
            dadaCorrecta = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que si no se ingresó un entero, jamás estás llamando a

```java
numero = scan.nextInt();
```

Entonces, siempre intentará leer **el mismo** valor incorrecto cuando intente:

```java
dadaCorrecta = scan.hasNextInt();
```

> Explicado con un poco más de detalle: ¿Qué pasa si se ingresó un valor
>   que no es un entero?
>
> 1. `dadaCorrecta = scan.hasNextInt();`
>      y `dadaCorrecta` será falso
> 2. `if (dadaCorrecta) {`
>      va al `else {`     e imprime en pantalla
> 3. Siguiente iteración del bucle,
>      imprime `"Entra un valor..."`
> 4. `dadaCorrecta = scan.hasNextInt();`
>      y `dadaCorrecta` será falso **porque está preguntando sobre la misma línea que recién**
>
> Esto es lo mismo que el paso **1**... ¿Se ve cómo nunca sale del bucle?

Si es incorrecto, deberías leer el valor para descartarlo con:

```java
scan.next();
```

Y así permitir que lea la siguiente línea ingresada por el usuario

A partir de esto, la próxima vez que se llame a:

```java
dadaCorrecta = scan.hasNextInt();
```

estará preguntando por la siguiente línea.

---

#### Código.

```java
public class Prubea1 {

    public static final int MINIM_NUM = 1;
    public static final int MAXIM_NUM = 15;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numero = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //modifico boolean dadaCorrecta a false para que entre el dato
        boolean dadaCorrecta = false;
        boolean numeroCorrecte = false;

        while (!numeroCorrecte) {

            System.out.print("Entra un valor entre 1 - 15: ");
            dadaCorrecta = scan.hasNextInt();

            if (dadaCorrecta) {

                numero = scan.nextInt();
                // pongo dadaCorrecta  a false puesto que aun no ha entrado.
                dadaCorrecta = false;
                if ((numero < 1) || (numero > 15)) {

                    System.out.print("vuelva a introducirlo");
                    dadaCorrecta = true;

                } else {
                    numeroCorrecte = true;
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("dada incorrecta, te que ser un sencer, torni a introduir un numero");


                scan.next(); // <------- Acá descartamos el valor incorrecto


            }
        }
        if ((numero >= 1) && (numero <= 15)) {
            System.out.println("ho has encertat");
            System.out.println("Correcto");
            dadaCorrecta = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Desde luego funciona, entonces la orden scan.next(); simplemente descarta el valor incorrecto, lo veo pero no enteindo muy bien porque funciona.

Comment: @Carlos Si bien lo estoy usando para descartar, perfectamente se podría usar para leer como `String linea = scan.next();` ... Mientras no leas la línea, `scan.hasNextInt()` seguirá refiriéndose **a la misma**. `scan.next()` es similar a `scan.nextInt()`, pero devuelve un string en vez de un int.

Comment: Claro, ahora si,se repite el ciclo como ya esta introducida vuelve al else e imprime, bucle infinito.

Comment: entonces en la linea scan,next (); lo que le decimos al programa es que vamos a introducir una nuevo dato, no?

Comment: `Scanner.next()` lee y devuelve la próxima línea ingresada, o incluso si no se ingresó nada bloquea el programa hasta que se ingrese una línea. En este caso, ya se había ingresado una línea, pero se quiere pasar a la siguiente.

Comment: Gracias, ya veo como funciona, me lo anoto